# R markdown - how to switch font to Times New Roman?

Tags: fonts, markdown

I gave up. I can't find any working solution to change font type in my R Markdown document. I tried a lot of stuff, for example:

```
---
output: word_document    
sansfont: Calibri Light
---
```

But RStudio just ignores it. Can you help me? I need Times New Roman font in my pdf/word document.

Regards

Comment: Note that "Document fonts (works only with xelatex and lualatex, see the latex_engine option)". So I doubt you can do this for word output. If you want pdf, then use xelatex or lulatex. If pdf is OK for you, then this may be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24421235/changing-font-in-pdf-produced-by-rmarkdown

Comment: So there is no option to change font in my word output?

Comment: Yes, it is possible to change it. This may help: http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/articles_docx.html

Answer (score 13):

This worked for me. Try using `mainfont` instead of `sansfont`, 
and set `latex_engine` to either `xelatex` or `lualatex`.

```
---
output: 
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
mainfont: Times New Roman
---
```

Answer (score 7):

Another option: for a pdf document, I used:

```
output: pdf_document
fontfamily: arev
```

In my YAML header.

Comment: Hi, I have a doubt. Whats the difference between set a font in my YAML and outside the YAML?

Comment: Hi Laura, sometimes you can set a font with a cascading style sheet (css) outside your YAML.

Comment: just to note that this works with pdflatext, when the answer above doesn't