# rmarkdown pdf font not available

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown

I have a similar question as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24421235/changing-font-in-pdf-produced-by-rmarkdown?rq=1), but I'm getting a different error. I want to set the `mainfont` in yaml to [roboto](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/roboto/), but I get the error "fontspec error: "font-not-found"" when I knit it to PDF.

```
---
title: "My Title"
header-includes:
  - \usepackage[sfdefault]{roboto}
  - \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
mainfont: roboto
---
```

Running MacTex 2016

```
sessionInfo()
#R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
#Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
#Running under: macOS Sierra 10.12.4
```

**Update 1**

It does work to define the font in `header-includes`, but it seems like the `mainfont` specification should also work:

```
---
title: "My Title"
header-includes:
  - \usepackage[sfdefault]{roboto}
  - \renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
---
```

**Update 2**

`monofont` also failed for me, but `header-includes` worked:

```
---
title: "My Title"
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{fontspec}
  - \setmonofont[Mapping=tex-text]{inconsolata}
  - \usepackage[sfdefault]{roboto}
  - \renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
---
```

What am I doing wrong with `mainfont` and `monofont` in the yaml?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This option *must* be indented. It worked when you didn't indent the option `latex_engine` only because it was ignored and not really passed to `pdf_document()` as an argument. R Markdown uses the **yaml** package to parse YAML, and you can compare the output when `latex_engine` is indented or not:

```
yaml::yaml.load(
'output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
mainfont: roboto')
```

Output:

```
$output
$output$pdf_document
$output$pdf_document$latex_engine
[1] "xelatex"

$mainfont
[1] "roboto"
```

When not indented, you were essentially calling `rmarkdown::render(, pdf_document())`:

```
yaml::yaml.load(
'output:
  pdf_document:
  latex_engine: xelatex
mainfont: roboto')
```

Output:

```
$output
$output$pdf_document
NULL

$output$latex_engine
[1] "xelatex"


$mainfont
[1] "roboto"
```

In this case, `pdf_document`'s default engine `pdflatex` is used.

I cannot say for sure, but I believe the roboto package is for pdflatex only. Your original example was failing because you mixed up `pdflatex` and `xelatex`: roboto is for `pdflatex`, and the `mainfont` option is for `xelatex` (which will be translated to LaTeX code `\setmainfont{roboto}` using the fontspec package). You can choose either way, but not both.

If you want to use xelatex, you have to make sure you have installed the font in your system, and you know the exact font name (case-sensitive). I guess the name is probably `Roboto`. Unless you have other reasons to use `xelatex` (e.g. you know the fontspec package well enough and want to configure more fonts), I'd recommend you to stay with the roboto package and `pdflatex` since it is simple enough and you don't have to learn too many lower-level technical details.

You may spend a minute reading this page about YAML: https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/r-markdown.html

Comment: very helpful, @Yihui. thanks for taking the time to clarify.

Answer (score 2):

Update: Yihui's answer comprehensively addresses the question

This is a problem caused by the way RMarkdown is parsing the YAML header. The `latex_engine` should not be indented and then it will work. Currently, I believe pandoc is ignoring the `latex_engine` command because it is nested in `pdf_output` when it is part of the `output` part. Below is the correct header:

```
---
title: "My Title"
header-includes:
    - \usepackage[sfdefault]{roboto}
    - \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
output:
    pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
mainfont: roboto
---
```

Comment: it looks to me like `latex_engine` should be the third level according to the [Rmarkdown documentation](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/pdf_document_format.html#latex_engine).

Comment: Good point. I was getting the 'font-not-found' error when I indented it, but it ran properly when I moved it up a level. I'm not sure if that's just a quirk or a typo in their documentation.