# Fonts for Rmarkdown document

Tags: r, pdf, yaml, r-markdown, pandoc

Here is a minimal working example.

````
---
date : 2018-May-26
output:
    pdf_document
title: "Testing Rmarkdown"
---

```{r,comment = NA}

Gender <- gl(2,1000,labels = c("Men","Women"))
SmokerM <- sample(c("Y","N"),1000,replace = T , prob = c(.3,.7))
SmokerW <- sample(c("Y","N"),1000,replace = T , prob = c(.5,.5))
Smoker <- c(SmokerM,SmokerW)

mydata  <- data.frame(Gender,Smoker)
table(mydata$Gender,mydata$Smoker)

```

This is a text in the body of the document.What font is this ? What is
font for the output of table ? How can we change these 2 fonts ? What 
other categories of items are there in an Rmarkdown which have different
fonts ?
````

My query is the following: What are the default fonts for an Rmarkdown document and how can I change them ?

While researching this I came across this page :

[Pandoc variables][1]http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#variables-for-latex

Is it correct that there are 4 fonts (mainfont/sansfont/monofont/mathfont) for describing 4 categories of output in Rmarkdown ? What are their default values and how can I change them ?

Comment: Check out this post [https://stackoverflow.com/a/65853007/15060591](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65853007/15060591) Maybe it can work

Answer (score 15):

LaTeX is used when you create a PDF file. And the default font used in LaTeX is Computer Modern. There are various ways to change the fonts used n LaTeX, but the required names are often not intuitive if one does not know LaTeX. An easier solution is to use `mainfont` etc. together with `xelatex` or `lualatex` as engine. You can define these options at the top level in the `yml` header using standard font names for your platform. Here your example document using Liberation Serif as main font:

````
---
date : 2018-May-26
output:
    pdf_document:
        latex_engine: xelatex
mainfont: LiberationSerif
sansfont: LiberationSans
monofont: LiberationMono
title: "Testing Rmarkdown"
---

```{r,comment = NA}

Gender <- gl(2,1000,labels = c("Men","Women"))
SmokerM <- sample(c("Y","N"),1000,replace = T , prob = c(.3,.7))
SmokerW <- sample(c("Y","N"),1000,replace = T , prob = c(.5,.5))
Smoker <- c(SmokerM,SmokerW)

mydata  <- data.frame(Gender,Smoker)
table(mydata$Gender,mydata$Smoker)
knitr::kable(table(mydata$Gender,mydata$Smoker))
```

This is a text in the body of the document.What font is this ? What is
font for the output of table ? How can we change these 2 fonts ? What 
other categories of items are there in an Rmarkdown which have different
fonts ?
````

The first table uses the mono font, i.e. Liberation Mono, since it is normal R output. The second table uses the main font again. See the [documentation](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/pdf_document_format.html#latex_options) for more details.

Comment: Dear Ralf, Many thanks for your answer. It seems to be that mainfont is the main font in the PDF, monofont is the font of output of code chunks.  I guess mathfont is the font used to output mathematical equations. Is this correct ? What does sansfont correspond to ? Can you please point me to the documentation where this terminology is listed? Also, I have posted a follow up query here. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50549961/making-the-output-of-table-in-the-same-font-as-that-of-the-default-font-for-the )

Comment: @user2338823 You are correct. Sansfont is used for *sans serif* portions, e.g. via `\textsf{...}`. For the details you probably need the documentation for the LaTeX package fontspec (with TeXlive `texdoc fontspec`) plus a LaTeX introduction.

Comment: I tried this example and got the following errors:                                                                  
 ! Package fontspec Error: The font "LiberationSerif" cannot be found.

! name = LiberationSerif, rootname = LiberationSerif, pointsize = 
! mktexmf: empty or non-existent rootfile!

! mktexmf: empty or non-existent rootfile!

! kpathsea: Running mktexmf LiberationSerif.mf

! The command name is C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Roaming\TinyTeX\bin\win32\mktexmf
! Cannot find LiberationSerif.mf.

Comment: ! Cannot find LiberationSerif.mf.

! kpathsea: Running mktextfm LiberationSerif

! The command name is C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Roaming\TinyTeX\bin\win32\mktextfm

! kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.

Error: LaTeX failed to compile test.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See test.log for more info.
Execution halted

Comment: @ForEverNewbie Do you have these fonts installed? Either as system fonts visible in other apps or within your TeX distribution?

Comment: @RalfStubner, thanks!, I did not know the WPS Office software i use only has a handful of fonts installed, so i guess i need to install the fonts i need. For what i could find, I installed the package `extrafont`, then used `font_import()` followed by `loadfonts()`, and then tried to render a pdf document again with different fonts that appear in the output for `fonttable()` , but none worked. Any ideas of how i should proceed?

Comment: @ForEverNewbie All that would be on the R level, but here you need the fonts on the TeX level.

Comment: @RalfStubner, oh i see, so how could i do this?

Comment: @ForEverNewbie That depends on the font and the TeX engine used. In this particular case, you would install the Liberation fonts (https://github.com/liberationfonts/) at the OS level and XeLaTeX will get them from their via the font name. However, these fonts where just an example because I had them installed on my system. With XeLaTeX you should be able to use any font that you have installed. You have to reference it via it's name.