# How to change the font style to typewriter in R markdown

Tags: r

I would like to write an article using R markdown. I would like to change the text type to `typewriter`.

I tried this but does not work.

```
p.caption {
  color: #777;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
p code {
  white-space: inherit;
}
pre {
  word-break: normal;
  word-wrap: normal;
}
pre code {
  white-space: inherit;
}
/* Whole document: */
body{
  font-family: typewriter;
  font-size: 16pt;
}
/* Headers */
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{
  font-size: 24pt;
}
```

Any help, please?

Comment: Are you rendering to HTML? Is there anything in your code elsewhere or any local assets that would make this CSS recognize `typewriter` as a font family? If you're relying on a CSS generic, that would be `monospace`, not `typewriter`

Comment: @camille Thank you so much for your comment. I really appreciate it. I am rendering to phf document.

Comment: The code you have here is CSS, which is only applied to HTML. To style how a file is rendered to PDF, you need to make changes that will be meaningful to Latex. [Here's one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50539913/5325862) of several SO posts on setting fonts

Answer (score 0):

Add this in the Rmd file before the first chunk :

```
<style>
div.fontdoc { font-family: typewriter;}
</style>
<div class = "fontdoc">
```

Comment: This would work if 1. the OP were rendering to HTML, and 2. `typewriter` were a recognized font family they had loaded. They're rendering to PDF, and whether that's pointing to a valid font family is unclear