# Change Latex engine when using bookdown when knitting Markdown to PDF

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, bookdown

I need to change the font of a PDF Markdown document. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24421235/changing-font-in-pdf-produced-by-rmarkdown) suggests that when changing the font in a PDF Markdown you need to change the Latex engine by updating the YAML to include:

```
---
output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
sansfont: Calibri Light
---
```

However, is it possible to change the Latex engine when using `bookdown`? I have tried to change the YAML to the following:

```
---
output:
  pdf_document: bookdown::pdf_document2:
    latex_engine: xelatex
sansfont: Calibri Light
---
```

but get the error:

```
Error in yaml::yaml.load(..., eval.expr = TRUE) : 
  Scanner error: mapping values are not allowed in this context at line 4, column 40
Calls: <Anonymous> ... parse_yaml_front_matter -> yaml_load -> <Anonymous>
Execution halted
```

I have also looked at the `bookdown` documentation but couldn't find any reference to the Latex engine. Does anyone know if it's possible to change the Latex engine with `bookdown`, or if there is another way to change the font when knitting to PDF?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct syntax for the YAML header is

```
---
output:
  bookdown::pdf_document2:
    latex_engine: xelatex
sansfont: Calibri Light
---
```

Note that `pdf_document`, which is short for `rmarkdown::pdf_document`, is fully replaced by `bookdown::pdf_document2`.